# xcrun upload build with what to test details

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcrun

I have looked through the [xcrun upload API](https://help.apple.com/asc/appsaltool/#/apdATD1E53-D1E1A1303-D1E53A1126) and do not see any option to add "What to test" comments when uploading an app. Has any one figured out any other approach to automate adding What to test content?[image]